# how to set value as state while using radio type input and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a registration form in my project with several inputs. I'm getting the values of those inputs and sending them to a server with a post request method. I've managed to most of the functionality correctly, though I'm struggling a little bit with the type radio input. Basically, I have a simple yes or no radio input, If the user clicks on the "yes" radio input, I want the state to be updated as true, if they select "no", then as false. I need to have the value in one state because that's how I'm passing it in the post method, so the state changes depending on the user answer. I have made a simple example of that in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-butterfly-h81tjw?file=/src/App.js). As you can see, I have a simple form with two radio type inputs, one yes and one no and I'm logging the data using react-hook-form's handleSubmit method. I'm setting the state as "true" when the "yes" input changes, so when the user clicks it and "false" when the user clicks on "no", however, when I'm logging the data, when I click on either one of those radio inputs, the state is always going to be set as "false", even If I'm clicking on "yes" radio input and I have no idea why, since I'm setting it as "true" on change. I'd appreciate any help, thank you !

Comment: your codesandbox not working

Comment: you sure? check again please

Comment: yes, sure, it show default App of codesandbox

Comment: okey I think now it should be fixed

Comment: your code is not working because you have 2 duplicate input with same register and name, so remove name atribute and register with different names for 2 input

Comment: If I do that, then I'm selecting both of the radio inputs and can't unselect either of them. check the sandbox

Comment: oh, i undertand. I have answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246315/discussion-between-ceaiius-and-iamhuynq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you set value of both inputs is same value (question state), so change each value to "true" and "false" and it should work

```
<div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label htmlFor="field-rain">
            <input
                {...register('question')}
                value="true"
                type="radio"
                name="question"
                id="yes"
            />
            Yes
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="field-wind">
            <input {...register('question')} value="false" type="radio" id="no" />
            No
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

you can check in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-tdd-i6d4b1?file=/src/App.js:296-818). Hope it help!